# millis() function always returns same value

Tags: millis, mkr1000

I'm trying to program an Arduino MKR1000 and I am using the `millis()` function to emulate a traditional timer.  The problem is that any call to `millis()` inside the `debounceTimer()` function returns the same value.  I only added the `Serial.print` to debug.

I left out a decent bit of the code to simplify your reading of it.  It works by waiting for an interrupt on pin 4 which then calls the `runTimers()` function and that calls the `debounceTimer()` function and within that the `millis()` function is called. The `debouncetimer()` function keeps getting called until the 10 ms has elapsed and then should end the timer.  The problem is that the `millis()` function stops returning a value that goes up.

```
#define doorIntPin 4
unsigned char sysEnabled = 0;
unsigned long debounceTimerPlace =0;
unsigned char debounceTimerOn =0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(doorIntPin, doorOpens, LOW);
  interrupts();
}

void loop() {

}
void runTimers(){
  Serial.print('r');
  while(alarmTimerOn || debounceTimerOn || enablingTimerOn){
     if(alarmTimerOn)
      alarmTimer();
    if(enablingTimerOn)
      enablingTimer();
    if(debounceTimerOn)
      debounceTimer();
  }
}

void debounceTimer(){
  unsigned long time = millis()- debounceTimerPlace;
  Serial.println(millis() & 0xFFFF, DEC);
  if(sysEnabled && time> 10){
    debounceTimerOn=0;
  }
}
void doorOpens() {
  Serial.print('o');
  if(!debounceTimerOn){
      debounceTimerPlace = millis();
      debounceTimerOn=1;
  }
  runTimers();
}
```

I suspect that in the background an interrupt is being called than increments the value `millis()` returns and somehow my external interrupt is disabling that.  I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never exit the ISR, hence all interrupts are disabled. Do the *minimum* work possible within an ISR, and have the main loop outside.

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is I'm trying to get the mkr1000 to sleep when not in use.  I've tried to execute the wait for interrupt function but i dont see how to.  Do you know how i could do this in the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about millis(), it uses interrupts to function, and so you can't call it within an ISR.  According to this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt, you should be able to use delayMicrosconds() within an ISR, since it (reportedly) doesn't use interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the millis() function stops returning a value that goes up.

That's right. The value returned by `millis()` is incremented by an ISR which won't be called inside your other ISR.

You can use `micros()` which *will* increment. However that will only be good up to approximately 1 ms. The main rule of ISRs is that you don't attempt to do delays inside them.